# where to write jquery ajax in yii form

Tags: forms, jquery, yii

I"m trying to write custom auto complete for text field. can anyone pls tell me where to write this jquery, ajax code for this textfield in yii..

```
 <div id="output" class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'id'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($model,'id');
      '$(function () {
        $("#search").change(function(){

      $.ajax({url:BASE_URL + '/controller/lookup/',
                    type:"POST",
                    data:this.value,
                    success:function(data){
                   $("#output").html(data);
      }
      });

      });
              });'?>
```

any help pls,

Many Thanks

Comment: You must place your jQuery code within a `$(function(){` call that also is wrapped by `<script>` tags.

Comment: thanks for your reply frn.. I'll add it. is that the correct syntax to include jquery in yii CActiveform for textfield???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript* instead of *Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript*

Comment: thanks for your reply harish.. I did try that yesterday itself..but its throwing error.CWebApplication and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "clientScript".

Answer (score 1):

You should just make a new file, call it, 'myFuncs.js'. Place in a directory within your Yii Web App.

Then, in your view, simply call the js file.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/your/scripts/myFunc.js');
```

Comment: cant we write in _form.php itself. rather writing in .js file and calling it.. here i'm trying to build custom autocomplete for textfield..

Comment: @Developer this is the least complex of the options. The other way is to do `$Yii:app()->getClientScript()->registerScript("id-of-script", "$(function(){$('#search').change(function(){$.ajax({url:BASE_URL + '/controller/lookup/',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:this.value,
                    success:function(data){
                   $("#output").html(data);
      }
      });

      });
              });", CClientScript::POS_END);` which seems incredibly overewhemling as functions get larger.

Comment: can you look into the following code pls...as request is not being fired to controller

Comment: @ohgodwhy.. thanks for your reply..can you pls look into my revised code..its not firing the request..